# How to get to divs a align side by side full page?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs. I am doing a site design where 1st div holds navigation among some other things. That takes 20% width of the left side along with 100% height. The remaining 80% is used for actual content display in the second div. I have worked at this for hours and no matter what I can't seem to get it. Can someone please give me a example of making the this work? I need the 1st and 2nd div to remain side by side but the first div does not change size. While the second does. Any help would be greatly appreciated Thanks.

Comment: Please show us what you already have.

Comment: paste your current code so that we could try it also

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner_left"></div>
    <div class="inner_right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;  
}

.wrapper{
    margin-top:10px;

    position :relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height:250px;
}
.inner_left {
  position : absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  background: orange;
  width: 250px;


}
.inner_right{
  position :absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:250px;  
  background:blue; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi so you have two div you can give them id. 
The first one would be "nav" and the second one would be "content".

Your html:

```
<div id="nav"></div>

<div id="content"></div>
```

Your css :

```
#nav{
   display:inline-block;
   width: 20%;
}

#content{
   display:inline-block;
   width: 79%;
}
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header-info">

  </div>
  <div class="stang-1" id="stang-1">

  </div>
</div>


    <style>
.header-info {
  width: 20%;
  height: 50%;
  background: green;
  float:left;
}

.stang-1 {
  height:50%;
  background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a fixed navigation to a percentage and expect it to stay that size (without Javascript), the percentage is always the percentage of the window.

EDIT: With media querys you could change the width dynamically to the window size, im my example if the window is wider than 800px the navigation jumps from 100px to 200px, this might help

HTML:

```
<div class="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li>First Point</li>
        <li>Second Point</li>
        <li>Third Point</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navigation{
    width: 100px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.content{
    margin: 0 0 0 100px;
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
    .navigation{
        width: 100px;
    }
    .content{
        margin: 0 0 0 100px;
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zer0ub7o/1/)

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you want to have both divs to have equal height?

If so, then you could use the body as a `table` and both div as `table-cell`, like this:

```
body,html { margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
body {
    display: table;
}
#menu {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background: lightblue;
}
#content {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    background: lightgreen;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/056a6au4/)

Comment: Never use tables for layout. Tables are for tabular content.

Comment: @Wavemaster, please read before you comment. I don't use tables, I use div and give them the same properties as a table. Nothing wrong with that, it's a clean and good solution. Using `<table><tr><td></td></td></table>` would be wrong. Btw, I'd rather use this solution then add an extra (unnecessary) wrapper div.

Comment: using `div` as a table in CSS still uses tables for layout. Just with a different tag. And layouting with tables is bad practice.

Comment: Layouting with tables is bad practice because: You can use floats, display, padding, margin, transform, transition etc. to layout a website. But tables are - as I mentioned - for tabular content. The urge to use tables for layout is from ancient times when we have no better possibilities.

Comment: @Wavemaster: then please explain to me why... A `<table>` is designed to show tabular data. A `<div>` is designed to make divisions, like a structure to your webpage. Making a `div` *act* like a table, doesn't make it a table. With only a few lines of CSS and just two elements in the HTML the problem is fixed. I really don't see the *so called* practice here...